# Google Apps Script and External API

Tags: api, https, google-apps-script, basecamp

If I am not mistaken, as per [UrlFetch Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_urlfetchapp) I should be able to call the [New Basecamp API](https://github.com/37signals/bcx-api/) from within Google Apps Script. I suspect my confusion comes from a formatting GAS mistake (and the fact that I am just beginning all this). I have googled this a long while. This is what I have and the error I get back from GAS:

myCode in GAS:

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = "https://basecamp.com/******/api/v1/projects.json";
  var headers = {
                 "contentType": "application/json",
                 "headers":{ "User-Agent": "MY_APP_NAME",
                            "username:password" : "user:pass"},
                 "validateHttpsCertificates" :false
                 };

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, headers);
var text = response.getResponseCode();
Logger.log(text);
}
```

GAS Error Message:

```
Request failed for https://basecamp.com/2166446/api/v1/projects.json returned code 401.
Server response: HTTP Basic: Access denied. (line 9, file "Code")
```

I hope this is a reasonable question and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The correct header for [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), which makes use of [`Utilities.base64Encode`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_utilities#base64Encode), is as follows:

```
"headers": {
    "User-Agent": "MY_APP_NAME (App URL/your email address)",
    "Authorization": "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(username + ":" + password)
},
```

Comment: @mat10112:  The information is all over the place.  I started with the link to the API in your original posted, where it's mentioned that you can use HTTP basic authentication. Since that's easier to use than OAuth, I went to Wikipedia to double check the exact header to use for HTTP basic authentication. I then checked out the [App Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) documentation page, as I knew they had some build-in utilities.  Then I just put it together.

Comment: Ok, I will search better from now on. I'm new so its hard to navigate when things aren't so familiar. Thanks again for the help. I would upvote if I could.